# AWS Lambda difference in days should be 3, getting 19097

Tags: javascript, date, aws-lambda

I have a AWS lambda function, part of which computes the difference between a previous date and todays date, adjusts to represent as days and then finally rounds this to the nearest number, so 12.8 days for example will be 13.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if Lambda has some different way of representing `Date()` functions, because upon logging the results of various steps in the process I'm getting some weird values returned and hence my function isn't working. Here's some code:

```js
const today = new Date();
let item = {lasetReceiptCreated: '2022-04-11T20:00:22.549Z'};

let lastReceiptCreated = new Date(item.lasetReceiptCreated);
let dateDiff = today.getTime(); - lastReceiptCreated.getTime();
let diffInDays = Math.round(dateDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

console.log('SkipDayCalc: ','\ndiff: ',diffInDays,'\ntoday.getTime: ',today.getTime(),'\nreceipt.getTime(): ',lastReceiptCreated.getTime());
```

The resulting log shows this:

```
SkipDayCalc:  
diff:  19097 
today.getTime:  1649963123100 
receipt.getTime():  1649707222549
```

So why is my `diffInDays` value returning as 19097? When I run in a node sandbox I'm getting the correct value with the same exact code.

Comment: You have a stray semicolon in the middle of the line `let dateDiff = today.getTime(); - lastReceiptCreated.getTime();`. `dateDiff` is set to `today.getTime()` and the rest of the line is ignored.  You do write "when I run in an node sandbox I'm getting the correct value with the exact same code", but I cannot believe that. I get `diffInDays` as 19097 when I run your code in Node on my computer.

Comment: You are correct, in my sandbox I must have corrected but didn't notice it in my lambda code, thanks!